# Typescript, Object is of type 'unknown'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this code:

```
const dataId = await getData(id);

const result = dataId.requestPayload.officePaymentId; // error here
```

I get `Object is of type 'unknown'`

The function `getData()` is this one:

```
import { Agent } from '../types';
export default async function getData<T>(
  id: string
): Promise<Agent<T>> {
  const Item = [something];

  return Item as Agent<T>;
}
```

the `Agent` interface is:

```
export interface Agent<T> {
  id: string;
  requestPayload: T;
}
```

How can I pass the definiton of the generic when I call the function `getData`? Or why I'm getting the mentioned error. Any hint please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass the type to `getData`

```
const dataId = await getData<MyPayload>(id);
```

where `MyPayload` is the type with the property `officePaymentId`

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.0.2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIHMLgDwBUB8yA3gFDLLAAmAXMgM5hSjoDcZyUEAjgK4QMAFOAE8ANgHs4NZLjYBfEiVCRYiFAFlhQsZMrF25cTBjAk2gLZYwASWkMmIdCQUk4dYSATIYPT2GDiIMiYYAAicGBwePgAFOxUtPbMJACUtAJQ4ubAdBDYGFbRhKTkCIEMyNaQ5sgAvMQJAEQAjABMAMyNADQc3HyCIhJStERGJmYiluC21I0ARnBQjXJybOycYDxQQRlZORAAdJx04qIAbhAxVRA1bmiYOAQp8opuHl4+fgFBkAwxKSVyMgyiAKpQInBbHVkHAAO5wYBgYIQMIQ7CabRDSixFodRrPRRA4HlJHHHiiJH1cGRWxHPr8MCY3QHMamCAWKy2FjIAD0POQ0EyUGQAAtoBADMTQadDhJ0DEyRSUs4SL8wP8gA)

Comment: Thanks, pretty new with generics, I get the idea now. I read the docs but wasn't that clear to me as this example. edit: sorry, I changed this answer as the correct one because was first.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is waiting you to specify the type `T` when calling `getData`.

To do so use the `<TYPE>func(arguments)` syntax, example :

```
const dataId = await getData<{
  officePaymentId: string;
}>('foo');
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FASwdgLgpgTgZgQwMZQAQEEDmVIB4AqAfKgN7CqogAmAXKgM4QziYDc5qMUAjgK5SMACggCeAGwD2CWqnzsAvsGAJ6IsElRxe6iCAlhU2CABEEEBAUIAKDtTqNmYTMACUdQTAkBbEPSi4sHAhLYjIKLgheGAMwikoqABoOcJ5+IVFJaTpYuNQJODgQFGERLyCASRkAcgAjBBgqpNz5JtR5VBVUbQBrMAkAdwNOwLwiBSUrFTUkKxdUAF5QjiR9RlQqMwRKhY7+hBAIQygTTdwcvIKiqBKyyEr7JhZ2CnlrKrgJCSqXdmXVw649F4YkO83Wm0qADouHwBBASpkqJD8oViqJbhBKr8KCswPQJGIoJDJJgrFUAEoAUQAygBVAAy+FQNEanAEwIgP2A8hcs3YQA)

Comment: Thanks, pretty new with generics, I get the idea now. I read the docs but wasn't that clear to me as this example.